# openFileDialog view excel files and highlight the last one

Tags: c#

I have a list of .xls files named by their timestamp in a folder. E.g 2013_06_11_13_05_02Report,  2013_06_11_13_08_02Report etc. I have around 100 files and the program is working totally fine.

However, I would like to highlight the last created file in the openFileDialog. How do i do that?

Kindly help...

Anubhav

Answer (score 0):

Something like this basically:

```
    string lastFile = Path.GetFileName(Directory.GetFiles(PATH_WITH_FILES, "*.xls").OrderBy(file => file).Last());
    this.openFileDialog1.FileName = lastFile;
    this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. this code puts the last file name into OpenFileDialog1.filename. But it does not highlight the lastfile in the list ? Any ideas please

Comment: Sadly there is no functionality provided to do that. If it is your intention to make it so that simply clicking open will open the latest file then this will work fine. You cannot, however, interact with list itself.